# htaccess not passing parameter to get in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a simple `.htaccess` file which is supposed to redirect users from `/listing/$id` to `/listing?id=$id`. I've tried and tested this script on another domain and it works, yet for some reason it does not work here. I had to alter a couple of things in the scripts, but the logic is almost exactly the same to the original. Maybe I've missed something, but here is the final `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# remove php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

# only allow rewriting to paths that don't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

# /listing/$id
RewriteRule ^listing/([\w-]+)/?$ listing.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

And then when I go ahead and try and retrieve the data on my server side, an empty array is returned. **listing.php**:

```
// will return array(0){ }
die(var_dump($_GET));
```

All help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: With what link are you opening listing.php?

Comment: @klediooo `www.example.com/listing/test_id`

Comment: @anubhava I get server error 500 as expected :)

Comment: ok that is usually result of `MultiViews` but it appears you have it disabled already

Answer (score 0):

I am able to replicate the problem and found it is because of the `# remove php extension` condition and rule. If I delete those 2 lines then it works as expected. It seems to me as though that rule is counter to the comment above it, i.e. it looks like the rule is *adding* the php extension not removing it as the comment suggests.

It seems as though `REQUEST_FILENAME` is being set to "listing" from the url, so if the php file is called listing.php then it will match the first condition but the rule can't be applied because the pattern doesn't then match.

If I keep all your conditions and rules as they are except change the php filename to "listingTEST.php" and the last rule points to that file then it also works because in this case the first condition is no longer met. e.g.

`RewriteRule ^listing/([\w-]+)/?$ listingTEST.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`